# Modelling a database for a shopping list - should I represent the scenario with a "redundant" relationship?

Tags: database-design

[I may provide some pictures later]

I'm facing this issue in modeling an entity-relationship diagram. I'll have a shopping list, where for each item the user inserts, it'll be associated with one product and many prices. Each price shall vary according to its product's brand and the place where it is available (i.e. a market or shop).

I also wish to provide the prices to other users, whose may not have access to the shopping list of who recorded it.

So I have product, item, price, brand and place as entity types, where item should be associated with many prices, and one product.

A price should be connected with one brand, one place and one product. Product is related to price, so anyone can find it, independently of the list item of others. It's also linked to the list item so a user can't relate more than one product to a list item.

Is it ok to "make" these two relationships with the product entity? Is there a better way to make it?

Comment: How sure price is an entity for you? Usually price is a single value, property of one or multiple entities related, but what would be the properties of a price by itself?

Comment: In that case, price is a very instable attribute. Some products can change its value each two or three days. Then at least a registering date to help calculate a "trustability", which is necessary since it will be inputted by anonymous people.